# T-SQL query and group by reporting help

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

So I have some data that looks like this.

```
`USERID1 USERID2`
    1        10
    2        20
    2        30
    3        40
    3        50
    1        10
    2        20
    2        30
    3        50
```

I want a query that produces the following

```
`USERID1     COUNT`
    2        2
    3        2
```

It's a group by query that shows me the count of unique USERID2 for each USERID1 that has more than 1 USERID2 associated with it.  God I hope you aren't as confused as I am by that last statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
SELECT USERID1, COUNT(DISTINCT USERID2) 
  FROM [table] 
 GROUP BY USERID1 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT USERID2) > 1
```

Comment: Not sure If you have to do count on "DISTINCT USERID2".

Comment: @Ashish - Dayton said "count of unique USERID2" - therefore the DISTINCT is required for the "unique"-ness

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
select userid1, count(*) from tablename group by userid1 having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try something like this:-

```
SELECT UserID1, COUNT(UserID2) FROM Table1 GROUP BY UserId1
HAVING COUNT(UserID2)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this??

select userid1, count(distinct userid2)
from nameOfTable
where userid1 > 1
group by userid1

Comment: You forgot the having clause.  I only notice because I forgot it when I first answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
select userid1, count(userID1) as [count] from tablename group by userid1 order by userid1
```